# Как предотвратить Process finished with exit code 0? (Python)

Tags: python, paramiko

Привет. Если запускаю скрипт без функции с использованием библиотеки paramiko - то всё ок, если же с помощью неё связываюсь с сервером по SSH и исполняю какую-либо команду удаленно - то скрипт отрабатывает, но завершается:  Process finished with exit code 0.

Как предотвратить завершение работы скрипта?

Comment: откуда вы знаете, что скрипт локально тоже не завершился? Покажите как вы команду локально и удалённо запускаете.

Answer (score 2):

`exit code 0` обозначает, что не было никаких ошибок и скрипт полностью выполнился и завершился сам по себе. Соответственно, это сообщение не надо предотвращать, оно свидетельствует о том, что всё отработало нормально.

Comment: не зная как paramiko работает, не очевидно, о каком статусе возврата речь (к какому процессу относится: ssh, remote shell, самой команды)